# add smooth effect when scrolling to element with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, smoothing

I have coded the following function that whenever a certain button is clicked, view is scrolled to a specific element that matches the 'href' attribute.

I would like to add a smooth effect to the scrolling. Right now it simply goes to the element.

```
<script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer>
    $(function() {

        $(".button").on("click", function( e ) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $("body, html").animate({ 
                scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top 
            }, 600);

        });

    });
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Probably you can look up here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/540858/Smooth-Scroll-to-the-Top-of-the-Page-jQuery

Comment: Wait, your `<script>` element has both a `src` and content, which means the content is ignored. Move that JS code to a separate `<script>`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_smooth_scroll.asp but be aware that CSS `scroll-behavior: smooth` is not well supported (not working in Safari, IE and Edge)

Comment: @KBell OP uses the jQuery/animate solution, which works fine across all browsers.

Comment: @ChrisG Indeed, it was only to complete a comment that has been deleted then.

Comment: @KBell [Please don't link to w3schools](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280478/why-not-w3schools-com)

Comment: Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfect just edit your code like this (see below).

You have written in on script tag which is loading external script file as well as inline script.

```html
<script src="/javascripts/application.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer> </script>
<script>
  $(function() { 
    $(".button").on("click", function( e ) { 
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $("body, html").animate({ scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top}, 600); 
    }); 
  });
</script>
```